# Clearing the value of a dynamically created text-box which is present inside the dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a table with four columns. Few text-boxes and a select drop-down are created dynamically inside the table, when the new form is loaded. I also have a text-box(Final Value), where the user will enter a value. This is how it actually appears:

```
ID |    Users    |   Values   | Values to be billed
 1 | (drop-down) | (text-box) |      (text-box) 
 2 | (drop-down) | (text-box) |      (text-box) 
 3 | (drop-down) | (text-box) |      (text-box) 
 4 | (drop-down) | (text-box) |      (text-box) 
 .
 .
 8 | (drop-down) | (text-box) |      (text-box)
```

The table has a "Total Value" at the footer. When ever the user enters the value in one text-box inside the table and moves to the another text-box, the value is summed up. At the end, value in the "id = total_value" and "id = value_to_be_billed" should be same.

When the form is submitted, I validate the Final Value text-box, value in "id = total_value" and value in "id = value_to_be_billed". All of these should have the same value. Then I only save the value taken from the Final Value text-box(since others have the same value).

When the new form is loaded, all those text-boxes and the select drop-down in the table and the Final Value text-box should be empty.

This is how I tried:

```
  HTML:
<div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-6">Final Value</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <input type="text" id="final_value" name="final_value" class="form-control" placeholder="final_value" required="required">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" id="value_table" class="table table-bordered table-colstriped table-hover display">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="col-sm-3">ID</th>
                                        <th class="col-sm-3">Users</th>
                                        <th class="col-sm-3">Values</th>
                                        <th class="col-sm-3">Values to be billed</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr class="odd">
                                        <td class="dataTables_empty" valign="top" colspan="3">No data available in table</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2">Total Value</th>
                                        <th>
                                            <div name="total_value" id="total_value" class="text-right" style="margin-right:13px;">0</div>
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            <div name="value_to_be_billed" id="value_to_be_billed" class="text-right" style="margin-right:13px;">0</div>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

JQUERY:

```
 jQuery("#value_table").dataTable({
                    "sAjaxSource": "db.php?mode=dataTable&id=" + jQuery("#id").val(),
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bPaginate": false,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bFilter": false,
                    "bSort": false,
                    "aoColumnDefs": [
                        {
                            "aTargets": [0],
                            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                                return data + '<input type="hidden" class="serial_no" name="serial_no[]" id="serial_no" value="' + row[4] + '">';
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "aTargets": [1],
                            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                                return '<select name="user_id[]" id="user_id_' + row[4] + '_' + data + '" class="form-control user_id"><option value="">--- Select User ---</option></select>';
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "aTargets": [2],
                            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                                return '<input type="text" class="form-control text-right" name=value[]" id="value" value="' + row[2] + '" onchange="jQuery(this).Sum(\'total_value\');">';
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "aTargets": [3],
                            "mRender": function(data, type, row) {
                                return '<input type="text" class="form-control text-right" name="billing_value[]" id="billing_value" value="' + row[3] + '" onchange="jQuery(this).Sum(\'value_to_be_billed\');">';
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                });
```

This is how I tried to clear the controls:

```
jQuery("#final_value").val("");
```

When a new form is loaded, around 8 rows will be created dynamically. The first column will contain IDs from 1 - 8. The second column will contain select drop-down, which will contain names of the users(making the admin to select the user). Each row will have this drop-down(it is created dynamically for each and every row). The third and fourth columns will contains empty text-boxes where the user will enter the values(these are also created dynamically for each and every row).

My problem is, when a new form is loaded, the first row(against ID 1) is getting filled with the data that was submitted in the previous form. Like:

```
ID|Users|Values|Values to be billed 
1 | Sai | 20   | 20
2 |     |      |    
3 |     |      |
.
.
8 |     |      |
All others are empty.
```

I don't know how to clear that(since it is inside the table).

This is how I tried to clear them:

```
jQuery(".user_id").val("").trigger("change");//(clearing the dynamically drop-down inside the table)
jQuery("#value").val("");//(clearing the dynamically created text-box inside the table)
jQuery("#billing_value").val("");//(clearing the dynamically created text-box inside the table)
```

I don't why that data is getting displayed when I load the new form. What's wrong with the code? What should I change or add to correct it?

Comment: Could you please do a jsfiddle or similar? this would make things easier for us to test your code

Comment: in your initialization code i can see `"sAjaxSource": "db.php?mode=dataTable&id=" + jQuery("#id").val()`. So what is this id that you are passing into the URL?

Comment: That is the form-id for each form. When a new form is submitted, that id will go as 0 and in the database, that form will be given an id.

Comment: @Daenu I don't konw how to do that(to create the jsfiddle), bro.

Comment: @duddosai - your first `mRender` has following code `<input type="hidden" class="id" name="id[]" id="id" value="' + row[4] + '">`. Here i can see a id given to each hidden field is `id`. So i think at the time of new form; the wrong value is getting picked up by `jQuery("#id").val()` code while forming the URL. Please check that area

Comment: @vijayP I even tried by changing it. Yet, I get the same result. Check the updated one.

Comment: http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html